# Pandas dataframe column re-ordering: example snippet

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Can someone tell me why the author of this snippet wrote line 2?

```
conv_days = pd.DataFrame({'click_day':range(nb_days), 'click_a':n1, 'conv_a':c1, 'click_b':n2, 'conv_b':c2})
conv_days = conv_days[['click_day', 'click_a', 'click_b', 'conv_a', 'conv_b']]
```

Line 2 seems effectively redundant to line 1.  I can't see what difference line 2 makes visually when I look at the frame `conv_days`, and removing line 2 seems to have no impact to the downstream code.

I'm sure this question is asked and answered already elsewhere, but I can't guess what to google for an answer.

Comment: Did you notice the column labels are in a different order? Although, why they didn't write them in that order to begin with, IDK. Maybe this is from before Python 3.7, when dict ordering wasn't guaranteed.

Comment: A more specific title would be great, like maybe "Why would you need to reorder dataframe columns immediately after creating it?" See [ask] for tips on that.

Comment: Why did I get the "-1" above?  I was just trying to get an answer to a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What line 2 does is rearrange the order of column in DataFrame `conv_days`.
Generally, this [[]] syntax is used to specify the list of columns you want to select/keep from DataFrame and their respective order.
From data processing standpoint it has no effect indeed, as it changes the order in which columns appear when you call `head` or somehow refer to DataFrame.

Comment: Oh yes, I see it now!  Sorry abt that; I'd looked at the code so long I just got blind to it.